# Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Please help me with this one. I have one post query and I want to save it into two tables seperately. But I encountered an error message from postman " Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "
Please help me! Thank you!

Here is my code below:

FirstModel

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const class = require('./classModel');

const SubjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
},
address: {
    type: String,
},
classes: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: class.schema } ]
```

})

Second Model

```
const classSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true
},
```

})

and here is my controller

```
exports.create = catchAsync (async (req, res, next) => {

const newSubject = await Subject.create(req.body)

let payload = {
    body : {
        ...req.body.classes,
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        golf_course_id: newGolfCourse._id
    }
}


const newClass = await Class.createClass(payload)

if(!newClass ) {
    res.status(201).json({
        status: 'success',
        data : {
            subject: newSubject 
        }
    })
}
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are trying to set your `classes` in your `Subject` before they have `ObjectIds`. In your `Subject Schema` you have the following line:

```
classes: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: class.schema } ]
```

Which tells Mongoose that you are referencing another model with it's assigned `ObjectId` but in your case when you try to save it:

```
await Subject.create(req.body)
```

These classes don't have ID's yet, so you need to create them. I wouldn't manually set them, when mongoose sets them on it's own. So the following would be a suggestion.

```
try {
    const classes = req.body.classes.map(async (className) => {
      const newClass = new Class({ name: className });
      newClass.golf_course_id = newGolfCourse._id;
      await newClass.save();
      return newClass;
    });
    const results = await Promise.all(classes);

    const newSubject = await new Subject({
      name: req.body.name,
      address: req.body.address,
      classes: results,
    });

    res.send(newSubject);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

This method creates the classes just like you had in your code but then it give the classes to the Subject **after** they have been created, that way the `Subject` can use them. Otherwise you will get an `ObjectId` error because you can't assign a field with a reference e.g. `classes: [ { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: class.schema } ]` without a `reference` to that item. By the way in your `ref: class.schema` just use `ref: 'Class'`

Comment: Hi, a big thank you! im still new in node js and your suggestion is useful!